# Django / PostgreSQL generic relationships with a TextField object_id field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a fairly basic looking Django model with a generic relationship:

```
class AttachedMediaItem(models.Model):

    # Generic relation to another object.
    parent_content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        'contenttypes.ContentType',
        related_name='attachedmediaitem_parent_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent_object_id = models.TextField(db_index=True)
    parent_content_object = GenericForeignKey('parent_content_type',
                                              'parent_object_id')
```

(irrelevant fields removed)

I inherited this codebase so I cannot fully justify all design decisions, however I believe `parent_object_id` is a `TextField` to support non-integer PKs on the related object (e.g. UUIDs). This model tends to relate to a wide variety of other models, so it needs to be very versatile in terms of what PK types it supports.

This is as-per the Django docs recommendations: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey

Now, this model:

```
class UnitType(models.Model):

    media = GenericRelation('media.AttachedMediaItem',
                            content_type_field='parent_content_type',
                            object_id_field='parent_object_id')
```

(irrelevant fields removed).

Note that I'm leaving the PK generation up to Django, meaning I'll get an integer PK for this model.

*Now*, if I run this

```
UnitType.objects.filter(media__isnull=True)
```

An SQL error manages to bubble through the ORM:

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = text
LINE 1: ...a_attachedmediaitem" ON ("products_unittype"."id" = "media_a...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

My understanding is that this is due to the difference in PK fields.

Short of changing the generic object ID field type to an integer field (not really an option at this point) - what are my options? Is this considered a Django bug, or am I holding it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this is actually a Django bug. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16055

It's 7 years old and no fix has been offered.